# How to install #hyperledger-fabric setup on centOS?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, centos7, ubuntu-18.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a server in my lab running centOS operating system, and i am connecting to the server using ubuntu installed on my windows laptop. I want to install hyperledger fabric on this lab server (centOS). but I am new to centOS as well ubuntu. have no idea, where to start and how. I need help to install hyperledger fabric platform on this centOS server.

have surf the Internet but not found any good information about centOS commands and support.

I need all steps to install hyperledger platform on centOS server.

Comment: start by installing docker and follow the steps in https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/tutorials.html

Comment: I tried all these ways but didn't succeed. they provide tutorials for ubuntu OS but my server run centOS. @Harshit